# View runs twice when HttpResponse if of 'application/pdf' type

Tags: django

I use Django 1.6.5.

I managed to view pdf in my google chrome using this code:

```
def generate_pdf(request):
    ...
    with open("students.pdf", 'r') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), 'application/pdf')
    return response
```

However I noticed that the view is called twice which isn't cool since I have pdf generation code in this view.

```
[31/May/2014 00:35:07] "GET /students/pdf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18040
[31/May/2014 00:35:08] "GET /students/pdf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18040
```

When I change the HttpResponse to look like this:

```
response = HttpResponse(pdf.read())
```

Then It will like the pdf opened in notepad. The pdf obviously doesn't render but the view is run only once.

Why adding just 'application/pdf' to my HttpResponse causes the view to run twice? :(

Answer (score 3):

Before, I tested this only on Google Chrome. When testing on Firefox everything worked fine. What was more weird for me was that on my friend's laptop everything worked fine on chrome (by worked fine I mean view run only once). Then I had this thought - maybe some of the chrome extensions caused this? The anwer is **YES**.
*My Google Chrome's AdBlocks caused the django view to run twice.*

Comment: In my Chrome happens the same. On Google Chrome run twice, while not having the AdBlocks extension. And in Mozilla worked fine.